# Отправка и получение пакетов с сервера Mail.ru Agent

Tags: сеть, email, c++

Протокол MMP. Скажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка. Программа отправляет пакет, а потом принимает пакет, который отправил сервер в ответ. Вот информация о отправляемом пакете:

- Пакет: Установка соединения
- Имя пакета: MRIM_CS_HELLO
- Ответ: MRIM_CS_HELLO_ACK
- Тип пакета: cs
- Описание: Первый пакет, отправляемый на сервер.

Проблема в том, что recv() возвращает нуль (с сервера mail агента ничего не приходит).
В общем вот:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include"mail.h"

#define SERVERADDR "94.100.187.26"
#define PORT 2041

#pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lib")

int main()
{   
    WSADATA wsadata;
    sockaddr_in addr;
    mrim_packet_header_t packet;    //Пакет

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsadata);
    SOCKET mysock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);    // Создание сокета

    addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVERADDR);

    if(connect(mysock, (sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr))) {  // Соединение с сервером mail.agent'a
        std::cout << "Ошибка соединения.\n";
        getch();
        return -1;
    }

    packet.magic = CS_MAGIC;    //Волшебное число
    packet.proto = PROTO_VERSION;   // Версия
    packet.seq = 1;//Это счетчик последовательности. В данном случае = 1
    packet.msg = MRIM_CS_HELLO; // Посылаемый протокол
    packet.from = inet_addr(SERVERADDR);    
    packet.fromport = PORT  ;// Рекомендованный порт
    packet.dlen = sizeof(MRIM_CS_HELLO);    // Длина

// Выполняем и выводим то, что возвращает send()
    std::cout << "send вернула " 
              << send(mysock, (const char *)&packet, sizeof(packet), 0);    //Отправка пакетов
    std::cout << "\nСоединение...\n";
// Выполняем и выводим то, что возвращает recv
    std::cout << "recv вернула "
              << recv(mysock, (char *)&packet, sizeof(packet), 0);  //ПРинимаем пакеты
    std::cout << '\n' << packet.msg << '\n';

    getch();
    closesocket(mysock);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, сервер просто обрывает соединение (результат recv() ноль). Возможно это означает, что он не понимает формат packet. Вы уверены, что поля packet д.б. в host, а не в network byte order ?

М.б. надо использовать htonl(), htons(), как в addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); при заполнении packet ?

Потом, странно, зачем в HELLO посылать серверу ЕГО координаты. Например в SMTP/ESMTP в EHLO/HELO клиент посылает серверу свой адрес.

Comment: в proto.h русским по белому сказано, что поля from и fromport - адрес и порт отправителя сообщения. Очевидно что оправителем MRIM_CS_HELLO будет эта программка